# Customising Lead Conversion in lightning Web Components

Tags: lightning-web-components, lead-conversion, popup-window

I have to customize the Standard Lead Conversion in Salesforce.
I have tried the below LWC as a Quick Action as shown in first screenshot.
Need to show the screen like the second screenshot as a popup window in Lightning Web Components.
Any help is appreciated.

HTML code:

```html
<template>
    <lightning-quick-action-panel header="Edit Fields Action">
        <lightning-record-edit-form record-id={recordId}
                                    object-api-name={objectApiName}
                                    onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Name"></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Phone"></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-button variant="neutral" label="Cancel"></lightning-button>
            <lightning-button variant="brand" class="slds-m-left_x-small" label="Save" type="submit"></lightning-button>
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
    </lightning-quick-action-panel>

</template>
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!
Chaitra

[image]